# Delphi 11.1 install freezes Installing "Core common Files Enterprise features", why?

Tags: delphi, installation, enterprise, rad-studio

RAD Studio 11.1, trying to install Delphi.

I have previous installs of Delphi 10.4 and 10.3.  I have an enterprise license.
I am installing on windows 11 Pro, 21H2, Build 22000.652, after running check for updates and a couple of reboots to apply the system patches today, so OS all up to date.  This computer was recently upgraded from win 10 to win 11 which may be part of the problem (?).

It freezes here, after downloading the "Core common Files Enterprise features" :
[image: RAD studio 11 install frozen]

I'm reluctant to uninstall the older Delphis until I know this one will work (I could probably get rid of 10.3...), and my colleagues on win10 seem to have installed ok with these older versions co-existing on their system.

Comment: Running different versions of Delphi on the same computer is not a problem. But Emba has some serious difficulties with its servers from time to time! I suggest you download the ISO installer from the download portal und and run this instead of the web installer.

Comment: Embarcadero provides free support for installation related issues. Open a support ticket with them, as they're the best resource for troubleshooting installer problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sophos antivirus was the culprit.  I notced in taskmgr that sophos was using a fair amount of cpu and the delphi installer only about about 2%, but its ram was usage slowly increasing, so no doubt if I'd left it long enough (hours) it may have succeeded.  Being more impatient, I had our IT temp disable Sophos, and it skipped though it in a matter of minutes.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Only for register:

if you run install in a user that is not the "Administrator", main user of the computer, this can happen.

To clarify, it is the "Administrator" user and not a user in the Administrators group.

Running with Administrator I had success on the computers that had problems.